# Chronoform 5 upload file get error only Apple device

Tags: php, ios, joomla, bluehost, chronoforms

I have a Joomla website. That is using Chronoforms5 to allow the user to upload a file to the server. I am using Bluehost server to store the website.
You can refer to URL:

https://new.ipshk.org/index.php?option=com_chronoforms5&chronoform=demo-fields-multiplier

That form is working fine on desktop and Android devices.
But when I choose multiple files from Browse of an Apple device (iPhone, iPad), I get a *400 bad request* when I submit the form.
I checked the log of the website. But I see no error log.
Anyone could help me know what is the cause of the issue?
Thank you.
Ha